# Главное окно шаблона TwentyTwenty-child

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на теме TwentyTwenty-child

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В папке `C:\OSPanel\domains\digitalshop.ru\wp-content\themes\twentytwenty-child` есть файл `header.php`

```html
<?php
/**
 * Header file for the Twenty Twenty WordPress default theme.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

    <head>

        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

        <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

        <?php
        wp_body_open();
        ?>

        <header id="site-header" class="header-footer-group" role="banner">

            <div class="header-inner section-inner">

                <div class="header-main-wrapper">   
                <div class="header-titles-wrapper">

                    <?php

                    // Check whether the header search is activated in the customizer.
                    $enable_header_search = get_theme_mod( 'enable_header_search', true );

                    if ( true === $enable_header_search ) {

                        ?>

                        <button class="toggle search-toggle mobile-search-toggle" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="toggle-inner">
                                <span class="toggle-icon">
                                    <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg( 'search' ); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                            </span>
                        </button><!-- .search-toggle -->

                    <?php } ?>

                    <div class="header-titles">

                        <?php
                            // Site title or logo.
                            twentytwenty_site_logo();

                            // Site description.
                            twentytwenty_site_description();
                        ?>

                    </div><!-- .header-titles -->

                    <button class="toggle nav-toggle mobile-nav-toggle" data-toggle-target=".menu-modal"  data-toggle-body-class="showing-menu-modal" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".close-nav-toggle">
                        <span class="toggle-inner">
                            <span class="toggle-icon">
                                <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg( 'ellipsis' ); ?>
                            </span>
                            <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                        </span>
                    </button><!-- .nav-toggle -->

                </div><!-- .header-titles-wrapper -->

                <div class="header-navigation-wrapper">
                        
                        <!-- <?php get_search_form( $echo = true ); ?> -->
                        
                            <div class="entrylink">
                                    <a href='javascript: document.location.href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/entry.php"'>
                                        <span class="eEkWAa">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/useentryicon.png" class="myalign">
                                            </img>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="gxtXIp"><?php echo " " ?>Вход</span>
                                        <span class="bidiEP">|</span>
                                        <span class="jCpPzc"> Регистрация</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            
                        <?php

                    if ( true === $enable_header_search || has_nav_menu( 'expanded' ) ) {
                        ?>

                        <div class="header-toggles hide-no-js">

                        <?php
                        if ( has_nav_menu( 'expanded' ) ) {
                            ?>

                            <div class="toggle-wrapper nav-toggle-wrapper has-expanded-menu">

                                <button class="toggle nav-toggle desktop-nav-toggle" data-toggle-target=".menu-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-menu-modal" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".close-nav-toggle">
                                    <span class="toggle-inner">
                                        <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                                        <span class="toggle-icon">
                                            <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg( 'ellipsis' ); ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </button><!-- .nav-toggle -->

                            </div><!-- .nav-toggle-wrapper -->

                            <?php
                        }

                        if ( true === $enable_header_search ) {
                            ?>

                            <div class="toggle-wrapper search-toggle-wrapper">

                                <button class="toggle search-toggle desktop-search-toggle" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="toggle-inner">
                                        <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg( 'search' ); ?>
                                        <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                                    </span>
                                </button><!-- .search-toggle -->

                            </div>

                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        </div><!-- .header-toggles -->
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div><!-- .header-navigation-wrapper -->
                </div>
                
                
                                
            </div><!-- .header-inner -->

            <?php
            // Output the search modal (if it is activated in the customizer).
            if ( true === $enable_header_search ) {
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/modal-search' );
            }
            ?>

                <div class="header-basket-wrapper">
                    <span class="basket-text">Корзина
                    </span>
                </div><!-- .header-basket-wrapper -->
                                

        </header><!-- #site-header -->
        
        <div class="main-menu">
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Адрес</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Телефон</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php
        // Output the menu modal.
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/modal-menu' );
```

Файл какой папки и с каким именем отвечает за вывод содержимого, находящегося ниже меню - `main-menu`?

Answer (score 0):

Для каждой страницы по разному. Читайте иерархию шаблонов: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете обратить внимание на код

```
<?php
    // Output the menu modal.
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/modal-menu' );
```

Это означает что он заберет и выдаст вам все что находится в файле modal-menu.php, файл находится в папке template-parts темы - TwentyTwenty-child, но если у вас нет такой папки, то посмотрите в тему TwentyTwenty.

Но учтите что для того что бы вносить изменения в тему вы должны будете скопировать соответствующую папку темы TwentyTwenty в вашу тему с тем файлом, который вам нужен. Что бы при обновлении темы не затерлись изменения.